# print item if it does not ends with a given pattern python

Tags: python, regex, string, substring, ends-with

I have a list:

```
mylist = ['summer_C','summer_C1','summer_P','summer_C123','summer_p32']
```

I want to print all items which do not end with the following pattern:

```
'_C' or '_C%' (int)
```

so it could be something like '_C' or '_C1' or '_C2939'

My attempt:

```
for item in mylist:
    if item[-2:] != '_C' or item[-x:] != '_C(INT)'
        print item
```

As you can see its not very dynamic, how can I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use a regular expression:

```
import re

numeric_tail = re.compile('_C\d*$')

for item in mylist:
    if not numeric_tail.search(item):
        print item
```

The pattern matches the literal text `_C`, followed by 0 or more digits, anchored at the end of the string by `$`.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> numeric_tail = re.compile('_C\d*$')
>>> mylist = ['summer_C','summer_C1','summer_P','summer_C123','summer_p32']
>>> for item in mylist:
...     if not numeric_tail.search(item):
...         print item
... 
summer_P
summer_p32
```

Comment: Good, but I think OP wants all that don't match

Comment: @JackFrankland: oops, missed a negative. Corrected.

Comment: Sorry Martijn but I failed to mention that I want '_C' avoid too, how would that affect your code?

Comment: @Boosted_d16: change `+` to `*`. Done so for you now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex for this:

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'_C\d+$')
mylist = ['summer_C','summer_C1','summer_P','summer_C123','summer_p32']
print [x for x in mylist if not r.search(x)]
#['summer_C', 'summer_P', 'summer_p32']
```

Regex explanation: http://regex101.com/r/wG3zZ2#python

Comment: Sorry ash but I failed to mention that I want '_C' avoid too, how would that affect your code?

Comment: "_C" at the end should be excluded too, so change `\d+` to `\d*`. The `+` means 1 or more characters, the `*` starts at 0 characters.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is really useful stuff, a lot of learning to do!